# What happens if a program makes an OABI style syscall in an EABI-only kernel?

Tags: linux, arm

Or more generally, what happens if an swi instruction with an opcode !=0 is executed on such a kernel? Does it produce a signal? I ask because I'd like to trap it.

Comment: I'd recommend digging around in the kernel source-tree. The SWI trap is, perhaps not surprisingly, one of the very few parts of the kernel in ARM assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I looked at the source but it's not exactly easy :-) so I could not get a definite answer from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that fields `swi` instructions is here: [http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#L335](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#L335).  I am not an ARM expert, but it appears that the CPU does not stash the `swi` argument anywhere the kernel can get at it; if the kernel wants to know, it has to fetch the instruction from the calling program's runtime image.  This makes every system call more expensive, so (if I'm reading things correctly) the kernel only bothers to find out what the `swi` argument is if it's compiled with `CONFIG_OABI_COMPAT`.

EDIT: The [ARM ARM](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/3d1/arm_arm.pdf) confirms that SWI does not do anything useful with its argument.  (Physical page 634 / logical page A7-118.)

Comment: You are right. This (http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/970771?do=post_view_threaded#970771) is the closest thing I could find, I'm trying to port it to arm and recent kernels.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to see what would happen. I compiled the following program and ran it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void traphandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
  puts("trap");
}

int main() 
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_sigaction = traphandler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
  sigaction(SIGTRAP, &sa, NULL);
  puts("begin");
  asm("swi 1");
  puts("after swi 1");
  asm("swi 255");
  puts("after swi 255");
}
```

and the output was:

```
begin
after swi 1
after swi 255
```

The signal handler was not called, nor the program was killed. Quite disappointing.